# Selenium RC cannot test on compressed html

Tags: testing, selenium

In order to have the fast speed of website, the web sever compress (gzip) the html files before sending to our clients. 
When running selenium tests, it shows a pop-up saying:
You have chosen to open
 ...
 which is a: Bin file
 from: http://...
Would you like to save this file?
"Cancel" "Save File"

It seems that the compressed html file doesn't unzip and browsers recognise it as Binary file.

Comment: I would say that obviously the question is, "how to solve this problem?". I too would like to know this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Selenium does this, because it doesn't seem to happen in all cases (in one case, a server that serves up gzip doesn't give selenium problems, but another server does).

However, after some research, I found a somewhat simple solution. Create a custom Firefox profile for selenium to use (you will have to specify the directory via the command line). Then, load up that profile and goto about:config and set "Network.http.accept-encoding" to "". Now firefox will not send out the accept-encoding header, and if your server is configured properly, it will not send back gzipped content in response. Then, your observed error should not occur any more.